# How to call a method by pointing with a variable

Tags: php

This night I have a problem. I would call a method from a class doing like this:

```
function callMethod($method) {
    $class = new Class();
    $class->$method;
}

callMethod('Mymethodname()');
```

but it tells me:

> Notice: Undefined property: Class::$Mymethodname();

Has someone solution for this?

Comment: please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `$class->$method();`?
but you should check if $method is a valid and callable function name before you try to call it.

`if (method_exists($class, $method)) $class->$method();`

Comment: yes my method exist and I will sure I use callMethod('Mymethodname()') in fact.

Comment: that won´t work, you still have to pass the function name, without the `()` to `callMethod` there is a big difference between them as part of the string and as put behind the variable.

Comment: No you're right luk !
I put th "()" in the string.. not when I called my method.
Thx guy !

Comment: are you sure it is working with the () as part of the string?
even if it does, i dont know if method_exists works as expected and in any case it is the better style to put it behind the variable when you try to call the function, at least just to make clear that you are calling a function here.

Answer (score 2):

its simple, you forgot the parantheses:

```
$class->$method;
```

should be

```
$class->$method();
```

Also, you should check if said method is available:

```
<?php
function callMethod($name) {
    $class = new Class();
    if(method_exists($class, $name)) { return $class->$name(); }
    else return null;
}
?>
```